# LibGDX (де)активация кнопки

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Изучал раньше Android там можно было сделать кнопку неактивной (setEnabled) , так вот как в libGDX такое реализовывается ? Уже есть что то готовое или самому делать ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение : setTouchable(Touchable.Disabled);